# Deploying a new version of WAR onto tomcat on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar, war

So I'm having this issue with eclipse and tomcat 6.

I am able to upload the first version of my war on eclipse using server(tomcat 6)->add resource, add all.

But then I tried editing some lines, and then run as maven clean->run as maven install, then clean, clean tomcat work directory, and restart the server, and it would not show me the reflected changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: until you are ready for a new build, you can just make changes and "Publish" to test, you shouldn't need to run the maven build.

Answer (score 0):

You clean your application, and executing an install, but seems you're not executing the build correctly. Ensure you're generating a new war file (take a look at the date of when it is generated to make sure you're deploying the last version). If your project has many modules, e.g: war and jars. Make sure you build the jars as well, and the jars are being replaced in the tomcat/libs folder or in your WEB-INF/libs, check the date of when are the depending jars generated too, then you can see the differences.

Best regards.